# understanding the finer detail of my pseudocode graph algorithm

Tags: for-loop, graph, linked-list, pseudocode, adjacency-list

here is my algorithm pseudocode:

```
input: a  directed graph G=(V,E)
output: all source nodes of G
function sources(G)
  for all u in V: in[u]=0
  for all u in V:
    for all edges (u,w) in E
    in[w]=in[w]+1

  L = empty linked list
  for all u in V
    if in[u] is 0: add u to L
  return L
```

what i am having trouble with is truly understanding this pseudocode, if it was written in c++ or java syntax i think i would have an easier time grasping the code. I understand the logic behind this code and how it generally works however i am still having problems understanding the finer detail of this pseudocode specifically how the in[w]=in[w]+1 works i understand that this code represents counting the indegrees and storing it in a in[] array but how is constantly adding one to in[w] supposed to represent the exploration of all edges and thus all nodes in a graph. can someone please explain in layman's terms the lines 4-7 of this pseudocode from the beginning of the first for loop to the in[w]=in[w]+1. also how should i think about u and w, is u the source node of the whole graph or is it just representing a non specific node that comes before another non specific node (w) that we are supposed to walk through in order to process the whole graph?

Answer (score 1):

```
Line 1 - Specify your input
Line 2 - Specify your output
Line 3 - define a function that takes G
Line 4 - set the array in to have all zero values for the number of vertices
Lines 5-7 - This looks like it's counting the number of times an edge goes TO a vertice.
Line 8 - empty
Line 9 - Initialize an empty linked list
Line 10-11 - for all vertices, if you don't have an an inbound node (since you're in in[u]) add you to the linked list L. 
Line 12 - return the linked list L.
```

I think what this psuedo-code is doing is trying to return a linked list with all nodes that are NOT RECEIVING an inbound edge. However, I'm not positive. Do you have any more context (like a book, page number, or URL that this came from?)

Good luck!

-Brian J. Stinar-

Comment: no your right, that's exactly what its doing, its trying to return a linked list with all nodes that do not have an indegree (source node). i am just trying to get familiar with this pseudocode syntax and be able to understand it as clearly as i understand c++ syntax, for lines 4-7 i understand the basic functionality of the procedure, but not the finer detail of how to use the nodes u and w. (i can read and understand the pseudocode, but if i was asked to reproduce i do not understand it enough to actually write it)

Comment: I don't mind pseudocode syntax, but I think the poor choice of variables (almost always present) is a mistake. It isn't much more difficult to say Graph = (Vertices, Edges) as compared to G=(V,E). I think instead 'u' would be more clear to say 'currentVertex' even if it's way more typing. That's just my opinion, and how I like to re-write code (and pseudocode) when helping people understand.

Comment: this is the code out of my solutions, so i did not write it, im simply trying to understand it. also if u is currentVertex then what is w? (nextVertex) to be explored?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "nextVertext" but I think "inDegreeVertex" or simply "vertex" would be a better name. That line looks to be counting the inDegree of each node, by checking to see if it is mentioned in any edge. Instead of "in" I'd probably call that "inDegreeCount." That was the most confusing line to me

Comment: Does this answer all your questions?